# don't want the last UITableViewCell's height used as the height for the subsequent blank cells

Tags: uitableview, height

I have a table view. When a cell is tap, it animates it's expansion to show other options. Actually, [this is what I've made](https://github.com/pachun/Nested-Table). The problem is that if the last cell is tapped, all the subsequent (blank) cells assume the height of the last cell. I don't want this to happen. It's ugly and frankly makes no sense. I tried adding a conditional in the heightForRowAtIndexPath. This does not work. I'd prefer not a hack, but if you find something concrete like creating an invisible cell at the end or something, let me know. I'm searching currently,